# how do I redirect a domain to another domain and on it sub directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, cloudflare

I run in to some issue recently - which I do not have much knowledge to resolve, so I'm asking stackoverflow community for help.

I have one server that I have 5 websites on - 4 of the websites are wordpress setup as a Multi Site - this works great no issues.

The top domain in the Multi Site is torbjornzetterlund.com - my 5 website is a standalone website that is installed as a sub directory. I have a domain name for this 5 site moln.co

I can access moln by entering torbjornzetterlund.com/moln/ - what I want is to use the domain name for moln.co to redirect me to the moln application and when it is redirected there have the moln.co in the browser.

I also using CLoudFlare in front of my server.

I'm not sure how to do redirect - do I setup page rules in CloudFlare do I add some code to the .htaccess file at root - I do not want to break another site that is running?

I appreciate any help

Thanks
Torbjorn

Comment: You'd probably add these rules to your htaccess file, but it'd be great if you could give us some more info on your setup (in terms of software, config, etc)

Comment: The setup is as follows -

Comment: My .htaccess file looks like this  at the root                                                               # BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?moln.co$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ moln [L]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [CloudFlare's PageRules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-) could probably help with some of this (redirects).

Comment: I have tried a few variations of page rules - I did not get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `.htaccess` file in your `/moln/` folder. Do the redirect in there to `www.moln.com`.